# How are the correct mysql script?

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql's script as follow as:

```
SET @waktu = NULL;
SELECT username, 
IF (@username = username, 
    IFNULL(TIMEDIFF(waktu,@waktu),0), @waktu:=waktu +
        NULL + LEAST(0,@username := username)) selisih_waktu, @waktu:=`waktu` as time
FROM mdl_temporer_log2 WHERE rolename = 'Student'
ORDER BY waktu
```

After, i run that script, it will show as follow as:

```
username   | selisih_waktu |   time          
-----------|---------------|--------------
aq         |   null        |     05:55:07          
aq         |   null        |     05:55:09   
megi       |   null        |     05:55:37    
megi       |   null        |     05:55:40         
megi       |   null        |     05:55:45
```

but, when I run it a second time,  that script will show as follow as:

```
username   | selisih_waktu |   time          
-----------|---------------|--------------
aq         |      0        |     05:55:07          
aq         |  00:00:02     |     05:55:09   
megi       |   null        |     05:55:37    
megi       |  00:00:03     |     05:55:40         
megi       |  00:00:03     |     05:55:45
```

I want to get output from that script as follow as:

```
username   | selisih_waktu |   time          
-----------|---------------|--------------
aq         |     null      |     05:55:07          
aq         |  00:00:02     |     05:55:09   
megi       |   null        |     05:55:37    
megi       |  00:00:03     |     05:55:40         
megi       |  00:00:03     |     05:55:45
```

So, i'm confused, are that script wrong or right? and if that script are wrong, how are the correct scripts?

Comment: "So, i'm confused, are that script wrong or right?" --- does it work as expected? If not - it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
...@waktu:=waktu + NULL + LEAST...
```

Why are you adding `NULL` here? `NULL` is not zero or anything, it is `unknown`.

```
Anything + unknown = unknown
```

Just remove the `+ NULL`.

**EDIT:**

Now that I read a bit more about it, this here

```
LEAST(0,@username := username))
```

doesn't make sense to me either. `LEAST()` returns the smallest argument, but you're comparing apples and oranges. The second parameter is just assigning a row value to a variable.

---

You should explain, what your query should do (with words, not just with tables), otherwise this question doesn't make much sense and is unanswerable.